# How to specify geojson layer order in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have 3 polygons, one is overlapped by 2 others. Is there a way to "bring to front"? Please show a programmatic example or demo of how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called [`bringToFront()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-bringtofront):

> Brings the layer to the top of all path layers.

Usage:

```
myPolygon.bringToFront()
```